# How to solve Invalid keystore format while building beeware android app

Tags: android, python-3.x, beeware

Tried to build android app using beware on windows.
Log file:

```
BriefcaseCommandError: Error while building project.
[12:18:50]                                                                                                                                                            console.py:305
>>> Extra information:                                                                                                                                     console.py:306
subprocess.py:675
>>> Running Command:                                                                                                                                    subprocess.py:676
>>>     'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\BeeWare\briefcase\Cache\tools\android_sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat' --list_installed                subprocess.py:677
>>> Working Directory:                                                                                                                                  subprocess.py:684
>>>     D:\Code\Python\BeWare\test\beware\helloworld                                                                                                    subprocess.py:685
>>> Environment Overrides:                                                                                                                              subprocess.py:694
>>>     ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\BeeWare\briefcase\Cache\tools\android_sdk                                                          subprocess.py:696
>>>     JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\BeeWare\briefcase\Cache\tools\java                                                                        subprocess.py:696
>>> Command Output:                                                                                                                                     subprocess.py:701
>>>     Loading package information...                                                                                                                  subprocess.py:703
>>>     Loading local repository...                                                                                                                     subprocess.py:703
>>>     [=========                              ] 25% Loading local repository...                                                                       subprocess.py:703
>>>     [=========                              ] 25% Fetch remote repository...                                                                        subprocess.py:703
>>>     [=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...                                                                       subprocess.py:703
>>>     Installed packages:                                                                                                                             subprocess.py:703
>>>       Path                 | Version | Description                    | Location                                                                    subprocess.py:703
>>>       -------              | ------- | -------                        | -------                                                                     subprocess.py:703
>>>       build-tools;30.0.2   | 30.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 | build-tools\30.0.2                                                          subprocess.py:703
>>>       emulator             | 32.1.12 | Android Emulator               | emulator                                                                    subprocess.py:703
>>>       patcher;v4           | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4           | patcher\v4                                                                  subprocess.py:703
>>>       platform-tools       | 34.0.1  | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools                                                              subprocess.py:703
>>>       platforms;android-33 | 2       | Android SDK Platform 33        | platforms\android-33                                                        subprocess.py:703
>>>                                                                                                                                                     subprocess.py:703
>>> Return code: 0                                                                                                                                      subprocess.py:712

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Console log:

* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

just run `briefcase build android`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can take these steps:

- Close Android Studio and any other applications that might be using the keystore.
- Open the directory `C:\Users\<username>\.android` in Windows Explorer.
  Locate the file "debug.keystore" and delete it. If you encounter an error trying to delete the file, you can try opening the Task Manager and ending any Java processes that might be using the file.
- Run the build command again using `briefcase build android`.

After these steps, build must be successful. Deleting the "debug.keystore" file and letting Android Studio regenerate a new one can often resolve issues related to invalid keystore formats.

Comment: This issue has also been reported on the [BeeWare issue tracker](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues/1112). As the answer says, the best workaround is to delete the keystore file, then run `briefcase` again.